# Auto popup based on JavaScript/jQuery cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, popup

I am trying to add an auto popup message in the website that depends in js/jQuery cookie, meaning the the popup will show once a day only to a visitor (instead of showing every time page gets reloaded)

the cookie will expire in 24 hours, once its expires the auto popup will show again.

Many Thanks

Comment: What's the question? Remember to add a [mcve] of your effort so far.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. My question is, how can I hook the cookie and my  popup(lightbox). So it can open only once a day.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code:

```
var currentDate = new Date().toLocaleString();
var alertCookieDate = getCookieDate(); 
var alertWasShown = getCookiePopup(); //set here boolean if popup was shown on true and false if not
if(alertCookieDate < currentDate && !alertWasShown){
   alert("popup here");
   updateCookie(); //code to update time here;
   updateCookiePopup(); //set boolean here
}
```